# Querying a registry key in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I'm using the following code to get a list of programs being run at start up, and log them to a file.

`for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" 2^>NUL') do echo %%A : %%C >> Log.txt`

This works with entries where the value name doesn't contain a space, but when it does, such as with "Google Update", it messes up the tokens, and %%C becomes: `REG_SZ  <path>`, instead of just the path.

Does anyone have a better way to query the registry and log its values?

Comment: what if you use "usebackq" in options  ?  http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.htm

Comment: Then it doesn't work at all. Also your link is dead.

Comment: if you use usebackq you need to enclose expression in the brackets with "`"  (button under escape)  - the link http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: @npocmaka Still doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got one working solution, I'd still love to see if anyone has anything better.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" 2^>NUL') do (
    set regstr=%%A
    set regstr=!regstr:    =^|!

    for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=  |" %%X in ("!regstr!") do (
        echo %%X : %%Y
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Version specific, works in XP, does not work in Win 7 - see comments for details.*

Columns in the output are separated by tab char (0x09), so use only tab as a separator:
`for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2* delims= " %%A`
This does not show well because of how markup handles white chars, but the character after `delims=` must be actual `TAB`

Comment: Doesn't work, on my system the output is separated by 4 space chars (Windows 7)

Comment: bummer! I noticed you must use different version of the tool, but quickly dismissed the idea they actually would make a utility less useable in newer release - and obviously I was wrong. Btw I just found this: [Behavioural difference of reg.exe in Windows 7 script vs XP script](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/ITCG/thread/62b13853-d39e-4780-8859-c696411da942) - it discusses some approaches - one of them being simply replace 4 spaces with a different char - maybe you'll find some of them usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way via WMI calling the Win32_StartupCommand class, results output to screen as well as a CSV file in the same folder as per script name:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    cd \ & pushd "%~dp0"
if exist "%~n0.tmp" (del /f /q "%~n0.tmp")
if exist "%~n0.csv" (del /f /q "%~n0.csv")
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path Win32_StartupCommand get /all /format:csv >"%~n0.tmp"
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 usebackq delims=, skip=2" %%a in (`type "%~n0.tmp"`) do (
  echo %%b, %%c >>"%~n0.csv"
  echo %%b, %%c
)
if exist "%~n0.tmp" (del /f /q "%~n0.tmp")
popd & endlocal
exit /b 0`
```