# Check registry values in windows batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to check the existence of some windows registry entries and their values in a .bat file.

So far I managed to check the existence:

```
@echo off

set SMB2_REGKEY=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
set SMB2_REGVAL1=FileInfoCacheLifetime
set SMB2_REGVAL2=FileNotFoundCacheLifetime
set SMB2_REGVAL3=DirectoryCacheLifetime

REM Check for presence of key first.
reg query %SMB2_REGKEY% /v %SMB2_REGVAL1% 2>nul || (echo Error! & exit /b 1)
reg query %SMB2_REGKEY% /v %SMB2_REGVAL2% 2>nul || (echo Error! & exit /b 1)
reg query %SMB2_REGKEY% /v %SMB2_REGVAL3% 2>nul || (echo Error! & exit /b 1)
```

How can I now check that the values of the three values (FileInfoCacheLifetime,    FileNotFoundCacheLifetime, DirectoryCacheLifetime) are set to zero?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874598/querying-a-registry-key-in-a-batch-script?rq=1

Comment: for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop"') do set doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "key=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters"
    for %%v in (FileInfoCacheLifetime FileNotFoundCacheLifetime DirectoryCacheLifetime) do (
        set "%%~v="
        for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "%key%" /v "%%~v" 2^>nul ^| find "REG_DWORD"') do set /a "%%~v=%%a"
        if not defined %%~v (
            echo %%~v is not defined
        ) else if not !%%~v! equ 0 (
            echo %%~v is not correctly defined
        ) else (
            echo %%~v is correctly defined
        )
    )

    endlocal
```